# help manipulating a 3D array

Tags: java

This game is a 3D version of tic-tac-toe with 3 boards. Each position on the boards are made up of [x,y,z] coordinates. x is the number of the board and y,z are the coordinates on that board. I'm trying to define a method that only lets you choose from the first board for the first 9 turns of the game, but am having problems. Here is the code.

```
public void set(Position p, int v) throws IOException { 
  if (board[p.x][p.y][p.z]!= 0) throw new IOException("Position taken");
  board[p.x][p.y][p.z] = v;
```

I'm not sure what to add to this method to only allow moves on board one for the first 9 turns. I have tried using a counter such as an if statement such as...

```
public void set(Position p, int v) throws IOException { 
                int counter = 0;
  if (board[p.x][p.y][p.z]!= 0) throw new IOException("Position taken");
  board[p.x][p.y][p.z] = v;
                  while (counter < 10) {
                  if (p.x != 1) throw new IOException("Invalid Move");
                  }
```

When I tried this and other manipulated versions of this same method I kept getting the "Invalid Move" error everytime, even when p.x was equal to 1. Any suggestions on how to loop this or any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: When you perform the while loop, `counter` is always 0...

Comment: Instead of `IOException` use `InvallidStateException` or `InvallidArgumentException`

Answer (score 1):

You really ought to do your own learning rather than asking us to do your homework assignments for you. I am not going to answer your question but I will point out that there are several huge problems with your code:

1: counter is scoped within the set method and will therefore always be set zero at the start of that method even if this is the 20th turn.
2: counter is never incremented and will therefore always have its initial value.
3: Arrays in Java start at zero not one.
4: IOException is not a suitable exception for this method to throw as it is not doing any IO.

Comment: Yes because I'm asking for help on one method I'm asking you to do all of my homework assignment...sure. Thanks for 1 and 2 as I instantly see those problems but for 3, yes I know arrays start at 0 but the first tic tac toe grid is set to x = 1, and for 4 the professor specifically asked to through an IOException then declare the error afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] **only lets you choose from the first board for the first 9 turns of the game** [...]

Note that the *first* element of an array has index 0, so you may want to change

```
p.x != 1
```

to

```
p.x != 0
```

---

Also, I think you have a problem with:

```
int counter = 0;
// ...
// ...
while (counter < 10) {
    if (p.x != 1)
        throw new IOException("Invalid Move");
}
```

as it will go into an infinite loop.

You probably want to have `counter` as a member variable and do `counter++` in the move method (if the move was successful).